# Is it possible to make app as device owner in the code?

Tags: android

I am creating a Kiosk type app that will run on company devices and the user cannot exit the app without a password. I am going to use screen pinning to accomplish this to hide the back and recent buttons. When the app is installed on the device I want to set the app as device owner. I tried running this command but its not working

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dpm set-device-owner com.app.nexus.nexus/.Admin")
```

Admin class

```
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
public class Admin extends DeviceAdminReceiver{
}
```

Comment: Hopefully that is not possible, for obvious security reasons. Otherwise, all sorts of malicious apps would try to declare themselves as a device owner app.